# Jquery post request with body and redirect page on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a situation in my website where in one of my webpage I have to redirect the page on reload. I combined various solutions I found out online to come up with this:

```
 $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
     function redirectPost(url, data,name) {

         var form = document.createElement('form');
         document.body.appendChild(form);
         form.method = 'post';
         form.action = url;
         var input = document.createElement('input');
         input.type = 'hidden';
         input.name = name;
         input.value = data;
         form.appendChild(input);  
         form.submit();
     }

   redirectPost("/incompleteOrder",$("#orderNumber").val(),"orderNumber")

});
```

This code should simulate sending a post request using a form during a page reload. In my backend Nodejs code I have a post url which basically does some database input and redirects to a get url to render the same page where refresh was clicked.

However the post request to `/incompleteOrder` does not even fire in my backend.

Comment: Why are you trying to build a form when the page is trying to unload instead of just sending it via .ajax or fetch?

Comment: You never submit the form. However I don't think you can do this in `beforeunload` event handler anyway. Explain your use case in more detail

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the form submit . I updated my question. The page contains a form with a bunch of input fields that gets values from ulr query string. The query string is build in the backend so that when you get to the page via the post route which builds my query string and then to the get route for rendering all of the parts are there. If you reload the page the query string is not built because you did not fire the route in sequence

Comment: It is really difficult to explain. But I just want some way to use jquery to basically act as if  someone clicked a post button in a form and redirect and completely ignore the refresh button